# In Rails, how do I generate Devise email templates to send to Mandrill

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Rails with Devise and I would like to use Mandrill to send out the different email messages.

I have found examples on subsclassing the Devise Mailer and using Mandrill, but the example uses Mandrills templates, which i don't want to use.

I would rather use Devise's email templates for this. My question is when I subclass the devise mailer, like this:

```
class MyMailer< Devise::Mailer
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer' # to make sure that your mailer uses the devise views

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    options = {
        :subject => "Password Reset",
        :email   => record.email,
        :name    => record.name,
        :global_merge_vars => [
            {
                name: "password_reset_link",
                content: new_conformation_path(record)
            }
        ],
    }
    mandrill_send options
  end

  def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    options = {
        :subject => "Password Reset",
        :email   => record.email,
        :name    => record.name,
        :global_merge_vars => [
            {
                name: "password_reset_link",
                content: new_password_path(record)
            }
        ],
    }
    mandrill_send options
  end

  def mandrill_send(opts={})
    message = {
        :subject    => "#{opts[:subject]}",
        :from_name  => "Accounts",
        :from_email => "accounts@example.com",
        :to =>
            [{"name" => "#{opts[:name]}",
              "email" => "#{opts[:email]}",
              "type" => "to"}],
        :global_merge_vars => opts[:global_merge_vars]
    }
    begin
      sending = MANDRILL.messages.send_template opts[:template], [], message
    rescue Mandrill::Error => e
      Rails.logger.debug("#{e.class}: #{e.message}")
      raise
    end
  end
end
```

How do i generate the email from the devise templates to send to mandrill?